# Dynamic refresh of a composite

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, custom-component

I have a tree viewer next to a specialized viewer. When something is selected in the tree viewer, details about this object are shown in the specialized viewer. `TreeViewer tree`, `Composite control`, and `MySpecializedViewer viewer` are instance variables.

```
public TheEverythingViewer(Composite parent) {
    control = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    control.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    tree = new TreeViewer(control);
    tree.setContentProvider(new MyContentProvider());
    tree.setLabelProvider(new MyLabelProvider());
    tree.setUseHashlookup(true);
    tree.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.BEGINNING, GridData.FILL, false, true, 1, 1));

    tree.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            try {
                IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
                MyClass myInput = (MyClass) sel.getFirstElement();

                if (viewer != null)
                    if (!viewer.getControl().isDisposed())
                        viewer.getControl().dispose();
                viewer = new MySpecializedViewer(control, table);

                control.getShell().layout();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (viewer != null)
                    if (!viewer.getControl().isDisposed())
                        viewer.getControl().dispose();
                viewer = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I just want:

```
+--------------+--------------------------------------------+
| + Node       |                                            |
|   - Node     |                                            |
|   + Node     |                       My                   |
|     - Node   |                                            |
|   - Node     |      Specialized                           |
|              |                              Viewer        |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
|              |                +--------+                  |
|              |                |        |                  |
|              |                |        |                  |
|              |                |        |                  |
|              |                +--------+                  |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
|              |                                            |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

The specialized viewer has tables that need to consume more or less space depending on the selected node. And currently, creating a new instance of the specialized viewer is much, much simpler than changing it's input (that wouldn't work ATM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't be recreating the viewer every time selection changes in your tree, you should just be sending the tree's selection to the existing viewer as its input, at which point it can do whatever you want it to do with the new input.  You're also never setting the layout data on your specialized viewer's control, and then forcing the entire shell to re-layout is wasteful.

Comment: Not recreating the viewer involves changing the structure of the table. If I don't force the shell to re-layout, what method do I call (on what object) to get the stupid thing to actually update the UI? I've never seen `someControl.redraw()` actually work in this case.

Comment: What table?  There was no mention of a table.  How would *not* recreating the viewer require changing the structure?  pack() and layout() the parent Composite, not the entire Shell.

Comment: I mentioned at the end, "The specialized viewer has tables that need to consume more or less space depending on the selected node." The pack() and layout() methods seem to be doing the trick. Now I'm dealing with a funny error where, each `pack(); layout();`, the table eats up more width, progressing father and farther past the edge of the composite.

Comment: SWT is a mite obtuse. There should really be refresh(int flags) with flags for redraw, pack, layout, refresh, etc. Not four different functions.

Comment: Don't use `pack()`. If you set layout on a container, all you need is to call `layout()` when its children changed.